# Toggle Button not doing anything when clicked

Tags: android, buttonclick, android-togglebutton

I'm trying to use a `ToggleButton` inside my Android code, but it seems that it does nothing within it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here it is the code:

```
public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   Toast t;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    }       public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        if (true) {

            t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anesthesia has started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
            Intent b_1=new Intent(StartActivity.this,TestService.class);
            startService(b_1);

        } else {
             t=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anesthesia has ended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

        }   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call your  `onToggleClicked` method?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    onToggleClicked(toggle);

    // Or set a listener that will be called every time the toggle is changed:
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggle set to: " + b,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This would call the method when the activity first runs and that's it...not when the button is toggled.

Comment: @colibriii are you sure this is what you want? See my above comment. No sense in it being a button, if so

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the `onClick` in your xml within your `ToggleButton`.

```
<ToggleButton
    ...
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

That is a user-defined method so you need to tell your `Button` to use that method (it could be named whatever you want). The docs link above also explains how to use the `OnCheckedChangeListener` if you prefer.

**side-note:** I think you want `if (on)` instead of `if (true)`